# Non-blocking sockets takes longer to connect on first connection

Tags: sockets, unix, timeout

I have a client application that uses non-blocking sockets to connect to a server over TCP/IP.

If the application stays idle for a few minutes, when it tries to connect to the server it takes a little longer and the select() call fails with a timeout. Subsequent calls are substantially faster and the connection succeeds.

When the application is coming from an idle state, the first connection takes more than 2 seconds. After that, it connects in a few milliseconds.

What can cause select() to timeout only in the first attempt after being idle?

Comment: Two seconds is absurdly short for a connect timeout. Try ten. Any expectation that it should always take less than two seconds is mistaken.

Comment: If the timeout is five seconds, even the first connection works fine. What I find strange is how long the first connection takes to complete, compared with the following ones. And all this takes place in a LAN, not over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

We traced the delay in the first connection attempt to the A10 load balancer.

The problem isn't fixed yet, but since we don't believe it is software-related anymore, I'm closing this question.